# React-native <Picker /> on android crashes app after render

Tags: android, react-native

Here are the components:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={'item1'}
  onValueChange={(value) => onDismiss(value)}>
    <Picker.Item key={'item1'} label={'item1'} value={'item1'} />
    <Picker.Item key={'item2'} label={'item2'} value={'item2'} />
    <Picker.Item key={'item3'} label={'item3'} value={'item3'} />
</Picker>
```

nothing unusual, no additional libraries just RN^0.29.0
Works absolutely fine in debug mode, but if it is being rendered in production, the app crashes right after render (I see the rendered scene for a moment and then a fatal crash).

I'm sure that was not happening some time ago, but rolling back doesn't help. I do not know what has caused this issue or when exactly it appeared.

I've tried to do `cd android && ./gradlew clean`, I've tried to remove some properties, etc - nothing helps.

However, while I was building-rebuilding prod app (`react-native run-android  --variant=release`) about 40 times, it actually worked a few times: render ended up successfully, then I left the scene with picker, and when I tried to get there again (render Picker again, it starts crashing). No idea what it is.
As you see, I've even hardcoded items there, but it doesn't help.

Any guesses?

Comment: Old question, but in case you're still having a similar problem, it would be useful to know about the error messages you got, if any.

Comment: Did you try run with debug mode and check the logs?